# Jackson-Databind: Compilation issue for the version greater than 2.9.10

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I am using the jackson-databind 2.9.10. I tried to upgrade the version.

I tried many versions. But, trying with the latest now which is 2.12.2

With all the versions greater than 2.9.10, I am getting compilation issue on the below code.

```
    Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> result =
    objectMapper.readValue(inputResponse, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
    });
```

**Issue:** incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds

Input response is on the string format of below json:

```
{
"config": [{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": [{
        "key3.1": "value3.1",
        "key3.2": "value3.2",
        "key3.3": [{
            "key3.3.1": "value3.3.1",
            "key3.3.2": "value3.3.2"
        }]
    }]
}]}
```

Comment: Depending on the version of Spring / Spring Boot you are bound to a certain version (range) due to API changes in Jackson.

Comment: I have tried that one as well. I changed the spring starter into the version which has the particular jackson mapper version higher than 2.9.10. Still, the issue persists.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.2.6.RELEASE

Comment: You cannot just change 1 version of a starter, you have to upgrade all of them. Mixing starters from different versions will lead to issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From jackson mapper 2.10.0 onwards, bounds of the TypeReference have to match the type of the response variable.

For more info:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/pull/2196